# Pip installation causes RecursionError

Tags: python, pip, drizzle

I am trying to install a software called grizli (https://github.com/gbrammer/grizli/) in a conda environment. In one step I have to install another software called drizzle (https://github.com/gbrammer/drizzle.git). Thís installation always results in a RecursionError. As explained in the installation instructions I run

```
pip install git+https://github.com/gbrammer/drizzle.git
```

resulting in

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/gbrammer/drizzle.git 
Cloning https://github.com/gbrammer/drizzle.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-ncjb9u8_
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-req-build-ncjb9u8_/setup.py", line 61, in <module>
    cmdclassd = register_commands(PACKAGENAME, VERSION, RELEASE)
  File "/tmp/pip-req-build-ncjb9u8_/astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py", line 140, in register_commands
    from .commands.build_sphinx import AstropyBuildSphinx, AstropyBuildDocs
  File "/tmp/pip-req-build-ncjb9u8_/astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/commands/build_sphinx.py", line 16, in <module>
    from sphinx.setup_command import BuildDoc as SphinxBuildDoc
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/setup_command.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 34, in <module>
    from sphinx.environment import BuildEnvironment
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/environment/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from sphinx.util.websupport import is_commentable
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/util/websupport.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sphinxcontrib.websupport.utils import is_commentable  # NOQA
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinxcontrib/websupport/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from sphinxcontrib.websupport.core import WebSupport  # NOQA
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinxcontrib/websupport/core.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 486, in <module>
    MutableMapping.register(LRUCache)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 158, in register
    if issubclass(subclass, cls):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 209, in __subclasscheck__
    ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 884, in __extrahook__
    if issubclass(subclass, scls):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1154, in __subclasscheck__
    return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 209, in __subclasscheck__
    ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 884, in __extrahook__
    if issubclass(subclass, scls):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1154, in __subclasscheck__
    return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)
  ...
  ...
  ...
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 209, in __subclasscheck__
    ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 884, in __extrahook__
    if issubclass(subclass, scls):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1154, in __subclasscheck__
    return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 209, in __subclasscheck__
    ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 884, in __extrahook__
    if issubclass(subclass, scls):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/grizli-dev/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1154, in __subclasscheck__
    return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-ncjb9u8_/
```

The three points in the code stand for the repetition of the three lines that always appear in the same order and probably cause the RecursionError.

I have already tried different pip versions but it didn't change anything. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same issue. The only solution that worked for me was to downgrade sphinx to a version <=1.5.6 as mentioned here: https://github.com/ericmandel/pyds9/issues/53 (note that I already had astro-helpers >=2.0 when I got the issue, so the solution is on downgrading sphinx)
Just do: pip install sphinx==1.5.6
and then hopefully drizzle will install correctly.